# Incorrect achievement link for edited post on another community

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, broken-link

I've edited a post on another community (blender.stackexchange.com).

I have been informed that my edit was validated.

[image: notification]

But the link inside the achievements' popup menu, is not correct:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86454/pose-position-to-reset-position/86479#86479
        ^---------------^
```

instead of

```
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86454/pose-position-to-reset-position/86479#86479
        ^-----------------------^
```

The hostname is not blender.stackexchange.com.

So, it seems that the hostname of these kind of links is the current hostname, instead of the "real" hostname.

Comment: Looking back at a very old suggested edit of mine in the reputation tab, I can also reproduce it - Approved edit listings in the Achievements tab use relative URLs (`/questions/...`) network-wide apparently according to Devtools.

Comment: [Positive reputation notification for edit approvals uses relative URL, which causes the link to go to the wrong place](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/391952)